# What is Reactive C++? (rxcpp)

Tags: c++, api, c++11, reactive-programming

Does anyone knows what's the use of rxcpp in a project? Is it just an another implementation of signals and slot or is it more?

Answer (score 1):

RxCpp is a header only library which depends on the c++ std library. It is a collection of algorithms for values distributed in time.

ReactiveX extension implements the observer pattern. The advantage is that it gives freedom from callbacks when you are dealing with a sequence of asynchronous operations.